# String match problem

Tags: c#

I have two strings:

string1 = "ABCD"

string2 = "-A---C-D-"

and I want to adjust string1 to become sth like "-AB--C-D-" which has max similarity (i.e. min Levenshtein Distance)  with string2.

How can I do that?

Thanks

---

Guys, thanks for replying.

Actually this is a biological problem : align two sequences.

Maybe you guys know BLAST (basic local alignment search tool) which fits I requirement perfectly. Just wandering is there any easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I'm reading for the fifth time and still cannot understand...

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: http://ashleyangell.com/2009/03/c-levenshtein-distance-difference-between-2-strings/

Comment: Hey guys, I believe the user is referring to the set operation of a UNION. Remember back from your Discrete Mathematics or from Finite if you were a business major, A U B = All of the elements of A and B combined whereas an intersection, A ^ B = All of the elements A and B have in common.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will need to play around with string1.intersect(string2);

Correction:

I have lost my head, you need a union, not an intersection. I am a mathematician and I still forgot. string1.Union(string2);

Comment: I don't know how `string1.Union(string2)` is going to help. That's just going to give you `ABCD-`.

Comment: Good point @Jim Mischel. That is an obvious oversight on my part. What are the rules for concatenation-- How are the strings to be compared? I believe you will probably have to do this manually (with loops and arrays).

Answer (score 2):

This is waaaay more than a union. BLAST is a complicated algorithm. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST

http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi

Have someone else do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess would will need to represent your sequences with something other than a `String` but I cannot suggest a design for such a class and its operators since I do not know anything about the biological stuff.